# How to save a form submission to an array of objects, then have submissions display on a different page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm making a student registry project where on one html page we enter the students information then when we submit the form it displays that students info on a directory on a different page. For the project specifications I need to save the data to local storage on the form submission page then retrieve it on the directory page. Currently I'm able to save one submission at a time but when makiing my 2nd submission it seems to overwrite the previous submission. To summarize, how to I get each form submission to display on the directory page without erasing the previous one?

On the form submission page this is the code I have:

```
                <script>
                    const form = document.querySelector('form');

                    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const fd = new FormData(form);
                        const obj = Object.fromEntries(fd);

                        const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
                        localStorage.setItem('form', json);

                        window.location.href = "allStudents.html";
                    })
                </script>
```

On the directory page this is what I have:

```
                <script>
                    const json = localStorage.getItem('form');
                    const obj = JSON.parse(json);


                    for (key in obj) {
                        const markup = `<div>
                                            <span>${key}: ${obj[key]}</span>
                                        </div>`;
                        document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML += markup;   
                    }
                </script>
```

Currently the submission must be saving the entry, then the directory page is able to display the one entry. But I need to be able to save and display multiple entries.

Comment: can you console log `const form`?

Comment: At what point would I console log it? I need to display each object in the array on the actual page.